# change localhost to 10.0.2.2 works for me

Tags: reactjs

componentDidMount() {     Axios('http://10.0.2.2:5221/api/mplans').then((res)=>{       console.log(res.data)     })   }

data is returned

expect to get this note in visual studio code so we do not need to google this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.